# How to solve the NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an    object.

Source Error: 
Line 34:                 <div>
Line 35:                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.accountStatus)
Line 36: (HERE)              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.accountStatus, Model.accStat) 
Line 37:                 </div>
Line 38:         </fieldset>
```

Following is the model that I am using.
I have created a List property in my model. And I am referencing it in my Html.DropDownListFor helper.
But I am getting exception.

```
public class OperatorModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Account ID")]
    public string accountID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Account Name")]
    public string accountName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> accStat
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text="ACTIVE", Value="0", Selected=true });
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text="DEACTIVATED", Value="1" });
            return lst;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Following is my controller code:

```
public class AdministratorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Administrator/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Read()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Disable()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Enable()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your model is null

Comment: Please could you elaborate your point

Comment: Can you please attach the code for the controller method that returns the view?

Comment: use `if(Model != null){}` wherever you are reading values from Model

Comment: I think the exception is being caused by accStat, but don't know how to solve. Because if I use Html.DropDownList instead of Html.DropDownListFor, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the OperatorModel to the view from your action:

for instance:

```
  return View(new OperatorModel());
```